# Is there a log4j appender that connects with TestNG?

Tags: log4j, testng

I use log4j and would like log messages that normally end up in my logging facility to appear in the test reports created by TestNG during my unit tests.

I think that would mean a log4j `Appender` which outputs to a TestNG `Listener` and an appropriate log4j config in the src/test/resources directory of my Maven project. Is that correct?

It seems fairly easy to write, but is there something I just can pull in via Maven?

Comment: This StackOverflow thread might be relevant for your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473911/testng-multiple-suites-possible-to-merge-reports

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and eventually coded an appender myself. It is actually quite simple:

Copy the following class:

```java
public class TestNGReportAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

  @Override
  protected void append(final LoggingEvent event) {
    Reporter.log(eventToString(event));
  }

  private String eventToString(final LoggingEvent event) {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(layout.format(event));

    if(layout.ignoresThrowable()) {
      final String[] s = event.getThrowableStrRep();
      if (s != null) {
        for (final String value : s) {
          result.append(value).append(Layout.LINE_SEP);
        }
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

  }

  @Override
  public boolean requiresLayout() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and configure it just like a console appender. E.g. like this:

```
log4j.appender.testNG=some.package.TestNGReportAppender
log4j.appender.testNG.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.testNG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just check the pattern. It is printing % extra at the end

Answer (score 1):

This post might also help you:

"[Integrate commons-logging output with testNG test case reports](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JGRP-851)"

Comment: Well, yeah, it helps in writing something myself, but I was looking for a readymade plugin or something. Still useful, though.