# Can you use TestNG Reporter.log() in @Aftersuite?

Tags: testng

I'm trying to access a centralized test-data object from my afterSuite class, and log one piece of data to the testNG reporter in the @aftersuite, with Reporter.log().

Here's my code:

```
@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void aftersuite()
{
    int count = glikkerData.getGlickers();
    Reporter.log("Number of glikkers:  " + count);
}
```

I am not getting the desired statement in the TestNG report.  Is 'Reporter.log()' invalid in an @aftersuite function?

**Update - Specific Scenario**

I have a TestNG project called "ImageManager". It uses a separate library I created called "CustomJerseyClient". This CustomJerseyClient project uses log4j to log connection errors from Jersey client requests. Also in CustomJerseyClient, I have created a custom log4j appender (I call this log4j appender 'TestNGReportAppender' - [see this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574139)) which adds all loggingEvents to a static array of logging events.

```
public class TestNGReportAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

   private static ArrayList<LoggingEvent> listEvents = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
   public static ArrayList<LoggingEvent> getListEvents() { return listEvents; }

   @Override
   protected void append(final LoggingEvent event) {
      listEvents.add(event);
      Reporter.log(eventToString(event));
   }

   private String eventToString(final LoggingEvent event) {
     ...
   }

  public boolean requiresLayout() {
     return true;
  }
}
```

The goal is to traverse this static array of logging events from CustomJerseyClient and count the number of connection errors, after all tests in ImageManager have finished.  The connection error data is already trickling upward from CustomJerseyClient to ImageManager (via the TestNGReportAppender), but right now I cannot get that data reported via the TestNG Reporter after all the tests have been performed- right now that data is stuck in the project.

Comment: Is the statement not showing up or does it have a different count than expected?

Comment: It's not showing up.

Comment: I just found [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/testng-users/8ncZt1ga7Bs/Jk287VvaoVcJ) which suggests (see the most recent comment) that Reporter.log() does not work in @aftersuite.  They suggest using onTestFinish() in ITestListener.

Comment: If you find that `Reporter.log(...)` doesn't work for you then you might try your own `Logger` per test using a `ThreadLocal<Logger>` (similar to how `Reporter` keeps track of the current test result). You'll then have to stitch each log file together in custom test reporter/listener or something if you want a single report with the respective logs for each test/configuration method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Reporter.Log will not work in after suite either directly or via TestListenerAdapter I just tried it.Can you tell me if your findings were the same as well?

Can you explain your use case exactly as in what do you want to calculate and what does your reporting mechanism look like? If its a generic use case I might be able to create something of importance.

Comment: Okay I updated my question with more detail.  I have not been able to get Reporter.Log() to work directly.  I haven't tried the TestListenerAdapter yet- I can will try that next.